# trying to count a value in multi column mysql php?

Tags: php, mysql

Look at my table below, I am trying to count the A in the table. A will only appear in one row, but sometime will be in the first column, sometime will be in other column, so I use OR, but it echo a number larger than 3, I only have 3 A, why? How can I only count 3 A?

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table WHERE first='A' OR second='A' OR third='A' AND number <= 7"

id  first  second third  number
1     A      C      B      3
2     C      d      F      5
3     A      c      b      6
4     B      A      c      7
```

Comment: It sounds like you want `WHERE (first='A' OR second='A' OR third='A') AND number <= 7`

Comment: Or how about `'A' IN (first, second, third)`?

Comment: @shmosel I think parameter in bracket must be a value not the column name. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @Mr.Engineer, you are indeed.

Comment: Can it be possible that `A` comes twice or more in single row?

Answer (score 1):

```
"select count(*) 
 from $table 
 where (first = 'A' or second = 'A' or third = 'A') 
 and number <= 7";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
(select count(*) from tablename where first LIKE '%A' and number<=7)
+
(select count(*) from tablename where second LIKE '%A' and number<=7)
+
(select count(*) from tablename  where third LIKE '%A' and number<=7);
```

try this code ,am sure you wil definitely get the right count

Answer (score 0):

You are going right just need to do two things:

- Combine OR condition into brackets ()
- Add backticks for MYSQL Keywords (second is a MYSQL Keywords)

**Modified Query:**

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table 
WHERE (`first` = 'A' OR `second` = 'A' OR `third` = 'A') 
AND `number` <= 7"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if `A` occurs more than on single row:

```
select sum(if(first = 'A',1,0)+if(second = 'A',1,0)+if(third = 'A',1,0)) as count
from $table where number <= 7;
```

SQL Fiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f34a8/3